# Can heavy disk IO cause non disk IO threads to slow down?

Tags: io, operating-system, posix

I am trying to understand the performance ramifications on a system that is under extremely heavy disk IO usage. Let's say the system is Linux based.

#### Setup

Let's say I have three processes **A**, **B**, and **C** running on a linux OS with a single disk.

**Process A** is just writing data to disk. For the sake of this thought experiment, process A is a c program that is using the posix `open` and `write` system calls. Consider that this process is writing so much to disk that it is causing HEAVY disk usage.

**Process B** is only making socket calls to some webserver, for example getting the contents of google.com. Some system calls involved in this process are `socket`, `connect`, and `write` (note `write` is used on a socket file descriptor, but not a physical file on disk).

**Process C** has two threads locking on the same mutex using pthread system calls.

#### Resource Contention on Disk IO Performance Impacts

What will the performance impacts be on processes **B** and **C** given that process **A** is doing very heavy IO?

Will it take longer for **Process B** to make its socket connection and perform the socket related system calls when compared to a system that was not under heavy IO load?

Will the threads in process **C** start taking longer to acquire locks on the mutex while the system is under heavy IO load when compared to no IO load?

Comment: Yes, very much so - tldr, albeit none of the juicy details. To get better responses, specify the _actual_ “POSIX” operating system, at a minimum.

Comment: Linux. I am interested in the details if you have the time to provide some :D

Comment: I don't see any reason why it A *should* significantly slow down B or C.  Of course, if A was doing something particularly stupid (like lots of tiny `read` or `write` calls), the unnecessary syscalls, context switches, and kernel overhead would reduce the resources available to other processes.

Comment: But is this a real scenario or a hypothetical one?  If it is real scenario, you need to provide all of the details if you want a real explanation.  Maybe even a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Real scenario. I have a lot of IO happening on a disk that is not capable of a lot of throughput, and I am trying to see if that is causing me to have some really latent / low throughput networking.

Comment: Are there any resources for me to learn more specifics on why it would cause non disk IO threads?

Comment: Well ... like I said ... I don't think that it should do that.  Have you tried stopping the disk I/O to see if the network throughput increases?

Comment: And are we talking about a real OS running on bare metal or a virtual machine?  In the latter case, you could be suffering under some resource utilization policy set at the hypervisor level.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment all else being equal or irrelevant, I would expect the slow disk to have negligible effect on network I/O.  In fact, a lower frequency of disk I/O completion interrupts could actually improve network performance when compared with a fast disk.  In general, I would consider your disk ops as "don't care"